# How do I retain files created during a unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

I am using VS2015. I have noticed that output files created during a unit test are automatically deleted when the test has completed. I am talking about files in the TestResults\Deploy_XXXX\Out folder. I would like to create and retain a report file in that folder. How do I keep it from being deleted?